# Given a directional enum, what is the smallest bit-wise method of inversion?

Tags: c#, enums

Say I have an enum `Direction` that specifies the cardinal (and intercardinal) directions:

```
public enum Direction
{
    None      = 0,
    Up        = 1 << 1,
    Down      = 1 << 2,
    Left      = 1 << 3,
    Right     = 1 << 4,
    UpLeft    = Up | Left,
    UpRight   = Up | Right,
    DownLeft  = Down | Left,
    DownRight = Down | Right
}
```

What is the shortest bitwise operation I can perform in order to invert an arbitrary direction while not introducing conflicting directions (Up and Down)?

I know I can handle this rather effectively using tertiary statements

```
public Direction Inverse (Direction d) {
    // Inverse of Direction.None should still be none
    if (d == Direction.None) { return d; }

    Direction dInvert = (d.HasFlag(Direction. Up)) ? Direction.Down : Direction.Up;
    dInvert |= (d.HasFlag(Direction.Left)) ? Direction.Right : Direction.Left;

    return dInvert;
}
```

But I would rather learn how handle this sort of "symmetrical enum inversion" with binary operators. The best I can come up with without just code golfing is

```
dir ^ (Direction.Up | Direction.Down)
```

but this obviously only  works if `dir` does not contain any horizontal 'components.'

Comment: Restructure your enum so that it flows from 0 to 7 in a clockwise fashion, then to "reverse" it you add 4 and clip to the last 3 bits.

Comment: I want to be able to maintain the individual components such that I can perform `dir & ~(Direction.Up | Direction.Down)` to extract the horizontal component for example. Thanks though, that is useful knowledge.

Comment: The way you have it structured it'd almost make more sense to do just up and left, and then have 1<<7 (or 31) be a reversal.  So down would be `Down = Up | Reverse`.  Also it might make more sense to start your bits at `1 << 0`  But maybe you have your reasons.

Comment: Lookup table should do the trick then.

Comment: What you have will not compile as the result of `d | Direction.Up` is not a `bool`.  Also you can technically have a value that is both Up and Down which seems wrong.

Comment: @juharr `|` is both a bitwise and a logical operator, depending on the operands.

Comment: ps--regarding my other comment, this is how navigation software works in parts.  You have an axis and then forward and reverse.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Yes, but the operands here are not `bool` and the conditional operator requires a `bool`.

Comment: Yes, sorry, you're right. Didn't understand what you meant by your comment.

Comment: you are right , I should be doing `d == Direction.Up)` Good catch.

Comment: @Enfyve No, it will not compile.  I literally copied and pasted it into VS and got the compilation error "Cannot implicitly convert type Direction to bool"

Comment: @juharr whoops, yeah, you're right, I replied in haste.

Comment: You wouldn't want `d == Direction.Up` becasue `Direction.UpLeft` is not exactly equal.  You either want `d | Direction.Up == Direction.Up` or better yet `d.HasFlag(Direction.Up)`.

Comment: Right you are again, today is not my day it seems.

Comment: @zzxyz I like the intuitiveness of that but given a forward component and a reverse component, I would have to have 2 separate `Reverse` flags, no? because `Up|Right` is ambiguous with `Down | Left`

Comment: One option here is to actually split this into two separate ternary values of Up-Down-Neither and Left-Right-Neither.

Comment: @Enfyve yeah that’s right. I’m used to my axis being a road :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The enum should look like this (shifted by one less, since `1 << 0 == 1`):

```
public enum Direction
{
    None      = 0,
    Up        = 1 << 0,
    Down      = 1 << 1,
    Left      = 1 << 2,
    Right     = 1 << 3,
    UpLeft    = Up | Left,
    UpRight   = Up | Right,
    DownLeft  = Down | Left,
    DownRight = Down | Right
}
```

Let's analyze different possibilities. Here is a table with the flags and corresponding inversions (only last 8 bits)

```
+-----------+----------------+----------------+
| Direction | Flags          | Inverted       |
+---------------------------------------------+
| None      | 0000 0000 =  0 | 0000 0000 =  0 |
| Up        | 0000 0001 =  1 | 0000 0010 =  2 |
| Down      | 0000 0010 =  2 | 0000 0001 =  1 |
| Left      | 0000 0100 =  4 | 0000 1000 =  8 |
| Right     | 0000 1000 =  8 | 0000 0100 =  4 |
| UpLeft    | 0000 0101 =  5 | 0000 1010 = 10 |
| UpRight   | 0000 1001 =  9 | 0000 0110 =  6 |
| DownLeft  | 0000 0110 =  6 | 0000 1001 =  9 |
| DownRight | 0000 1010 = 10 | 0000 0101 =  5 |
+-----------+----------------+----------------+
```

The composed directions can be inverted with `~dir & 0b1111`, but I don't see a simple bitwise operation for the simple directions.

Let's look at the decimal values. We could try to infer a function.

```
  inv.
   ^
10 |              X
 9 |                 X
 8 |           X
 7 |
 6 |                          X
 5 |                             X
 4 |                       X
 3 |
 2 |  X
 1 |     X
 0 X--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--> flag
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

This does not look simple either.

[WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com) can interpolate a polynomial from these number pairs

> [InterpolatingPolynomial[{{0, 0}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}, {4, 8},  {5, 10},  {6, 9}, {8, 4}, {9, 6},{10, 5}}, x]](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=InterpolatingPolynomial%5B%7B%7B0,%200%7D,%20%7B1,%202%7D,%20%7B2,%201%7D,%20%7B4,%208%7D,%20%20%7B5,%2010%7D,%20%20%7B6,%209%7D,%20%7B8,%204%7D,%20%7B9,%206%7D,%7B10,%205%7D%7D,%20x%5D)

The result is:

> -(x (x<sup>7</sup> - 40 x<sup>6</sup> + 686 x<sup>5</sup> - 6580 x<sup>4</sup> + 37709 x<sup>3</sup> - 124180 x<sup>2</sup> + 203524 x - 131280))/10080

uugh!

I would make an inversion dictionary

```
var inversion = new Dictionary<Direction, Direction> {
    [Direction.None]      = Direction.None,
    [Direction.Up]        = Direction.Down,
    [Direction.Down]      = Direction.Up,
    [Direction.Left]      = Direction.Right,
    [Direction.Right]     = Direction.Left,
    [Direction.UpLeft]    = Direction.DownRight,
    [Direction.UpRight]   = Direction.DownLeft,
    [Direction.DownLeft]  = Direction.UpRight,
    [Direction.DownRight] = Direction.UpLeft
}
```

and get the inverted direction with

```
Direction invDir = inversion[dir];
```

---

Finally, I found a **simple solution** using negative enum values:

If you declare the enum like this:

```
public enum Direction
{
    None = 0,
    Up = 1,
    Down = -1,
    Left = 4,
    Right = -4,
    UpLeft = Up + Left,
    UpRight = Up + Right,
    DownLeft = Down + Left,
    DownRight = Down + Right
}
```

You can get the inverted direction by taking the negative value using the two's complement
**`~d + 1`**

```
foreach (Direction d in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Direction))) {
    Console.WriteLine($"{d}  ===> {~d + 1}");
}
```

Prints

> None  ===> None
>   Up  ===> Down
>   DownLeft  ===> UpRight
>   Left  ===> Right
>   UpLeft  ===> DownRight
>   DownRight  ===> UpLeft
>   Right  ===> Left
>   UpRight  ===> DownLeft
>   Down  ===> Up

Simply using `-d` doesn't work because `-` cannot be applied to enums. You would have to write `(Direction)(-((int)dir))`.

Comment: +1 for taking the time to do a mathematical approach, and a lookup table like this is probably smarter and more lightweight than a whole method, although optimization isn't a factor. However, we both overlooked the translative symmetry in the plot that suggests bit shifting as a posibility.

Comment: In regards to your recent edit, `Up + Right`(-3) is ambiguous with `Down + Left`(-3) no?

Comment: No, Up(1) + Right(-4) = -3 and Down(-1) + Left(4) = 3. One result is negative and the other one positive. The console test proves the correctness.

Comment: Ah yes, it seems I cannot do math today at all.

Comment: I'm marking this answer correct, as utilizing negative values for an enum is an ultimately intuitive solution I did not consider. It also provides a more 'correct' solution, you can't get a shorter bitwise calculation than 2's compliment afaik.

Answer (score 3):

I have encoded the directions in two pairs of bits, one pair for vertical and one pair for horizontal:

```
enum Direction
{
    None      = 0b00_00,
    Down      = 0b00_01,
    Up        = 0b00_10,
    Right     = 0b01_00,
    DownRight = 0b01_01,
    UpRight   = 0b01_10,
    Left      = 0b10_00,
    DownLeft  = 0b10_01,
    UpLeft    = 0b10_10
}

static Direction Inverse(Direction dir)
{
    int d = (int)dir;
    Direction ret = (Direction)(((d & 0b01_01) << 1) | 
                                ((d & 0b10_10) >> 1));

    return ret;
}

static bool HasDir(Direction dir, Direction query)
{
    return query == (Direction)((int)query & (int)dir);
}

static bool HasUp(Direction dir)
{
    return HasDir(dir, Direction.Up);
}

static bool HasDown(Direction dir)
{
    return HasDir(dir, Direction.Down);
}

static bool HasRight(Direction dir)
{
    return HasDir(dir, Direction.Right);
}

static bool HasLeft(Direction dir)
{
    return HasDir(dir, Direction.Left);
}

private static string show(Direction dir)
{
    return (HasDown(dir) ? "V" : HasUp(dir) ? "^" : "") +
           (HasLeft(dir) ? "<" : HasRight(dir) ? ">" : "");
}


static void Main(string[] args)
{
    foreach(Direction dir in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Direction)))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(show(dir) + " " + show(Inverse(dir)));
    }

    Console.WriteLine("ciao!");
}
```

The `Inverse` operation just has to swap the two pairs.

Comment: +1 This is exactly the bitwise operation I was looking for. I think that a wiser option would be to use a lookup table, however I was primarily concerned with solving this with unary/binary operators.

Answer (score 0):

juharr offered a comment on your question that was along the lines of what I was thinking. Namely: are you sure it makes sense to represent a direction as a combination of four two-bit values? As you noted, many of the possible combinations are invalid, since you can't have opposing directions in the same value. Rather, perhaps a combination of two three-bit values would be more appropriate: one to represent the horizontal direction and one to represent the vertical.

Here's an example of what that might look like. `Direction` is a struct offering properties that yield the horizontal and vertical components, and a simple method for inversion.

```
public enum HorizontalDirection
{
    Left = -1,
    None = 0,
    Right = 1,
}

public enum VerticalDirection
{
    Up = -1,
    None = 0,
    Down = 1,
}

public struct Direction
{
    public Direction(HorizontalDirection h) : this(h, VerticalDirection.None) { }
    public Direction(VerticalDirection v) : this(HorizontalDirection.None, v) { }

    public Direction(HorizontalDirection h, VerticalDirection v)
    {
        HorizontalComponent = h;
        VerticalComponent = v;
    }

    public HorizontalDirection HorizontalComponent { get; }
    public VerticalDirection VerticalComponent { get; }

    public Direction Invert() => new Direction(
        (HorizontalDirection)(-(int)HorizontalComponent),
        (VerticalDirection)(-(int)VerticalComponent));
}
```